# Does the series $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n\pi)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n\pi)$ converge or diverge?

On substituting values I get alternate $1$ and $-1$.

So taking sum of infinite GP, I get $\dfrac 1 2$. So it looks like it converges.

Comment: Try to write out some values of $a_n$. What do you see?

Comment: @NigelOvermars I get altternate 1 and -1.

Comment: @user293702 So what does that tell you?

Comment: @NigelOvermars I edited my question

Comment: That succession does no converge. You can regularize it, anyway. :)

Comment: Actually the series diverge but it can made to converge to $\frac 12$ by summation methods. It depends on what level are you doing math.

Comment: @user293702 Are you talking about the sequence $\{a_n\}$ or the sum $S_n = a_1 + ... + a_n$?

Comment: @RenatoFaraone I made a mistake

Comment: @NigelOvermars Its series sum actually, Sorry

Comment: Actually your guess is right: the formula for gp summation cannot be used in this case by convergence criterion but you can use some strong summation method that allows you to use it anyway and get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **sequence** $\{a_n\}$ defined by $a_n = \cos(n \pi)$ diverges, since we have $a_{2n} = 1$ and $a_{2n+1} = -1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \}$. Hence two different subsequences have different limits, which implies divergence .

The **series (sum)** $S_n = a_1 + ... + a_n$ also diverges, since we have, following the same line of reasoning, $S_{2n} = 0$ and $S_{2n+1}=-1$. Hence the series also diverges.

Comment: What about the sum of an infinite GP which turns out to be 1/2

Comment: You should check the conditions for applying the formula of a geometric progression. And look at this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot.