# Find sum of given series if possible $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (n \pi )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (n \pi )$$

This question has been asked before 
[Does the series $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n\pi)$ converge or diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547657/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-cosn-pi-converge-or-diverge)
But I think the series diverges because it is not a single value. The results are alternating between and 1 and -1.

Comment: Do you disagree with the given answer in the question you linked in any way?

Comment: I second Arthur's comment. The answer to the linked question clearly states that the series diverges. This is a duplicate

Comment: It diverges. The sum does not exist.